# how to prevent deleted tds getting replaced by next td

Tags: html, css, angular

I noticed that when i delete a td it gets replaced by the one below it and its an issue because when the rows in my first column are empty the get populated with the data from the next column. What is causing this? and how do I make it so if a column row is empty it stays empty and nothing moves in the grid's cant seem to find what CSS styles causes this ?

Comment: If you delete a `<td>` element that's the expected result. Consider using an empty `<td>` element if you want to show an empty element.

Comment: Rather than deleting the `<td>`, why not just clear the content of it instead. That way the table stays formatted correctly. Not sure how you are deleting it currently, but if you have the element reference you could do `element.innerHTML = "";` which will clear the content of the element.

Comment: You could also do this if you wanted to avoid using innerHTML: `while(element.firstChild){
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}`